# Download complex schema / wsdl in gradle or via xjc

Tags: java, web-services, gradle, jaxb, wsdl

I've complex WSDLs with a lot of imports.

My goal is do compilation possible when network is down. So I want to download all WSDLs with all imports.

All works good, when I do:

```
xjc.exe http://my_complex.wsdl -wsdl -d d:\generated\
```

So is there any possibility do download my_complex.wsdl via xjc.exe ? (I didn't find anything in documentation).

Alo I've tried [this plugin](https://github.com/d10xa/gradle-download-xml-plugin) but its pretty raw, and dint get all dependencies.

So can you please advice something for me ? or please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP UI fix my issue, but its UI tool